# Use the output(StreamReader) line as file name(rename)

Tags: c#, file, replace, rename, streamreader

I am trying to use the output("line")as a new file name(files already exist, just rename).
e.g. "A,tampqer,n:.jpg"
but it looks like:
e.g. line ="A\tampqer\tn:\t\t"

I get an error: illegal character for the file name.

```
            int counter = 0;

        string line;

        // Read the file and display it line by line.


        StreamReader file = new StreamReader(@"C:\\german-czech.txt");
        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            //replace /t doesnt work
            for (int i = 0; i < line.Length; i++)
            {
                if (line[i] == '\t')
                {
                    line.Replace(line[i], ',');
                }
            }

            //Console.WriteLine(string.Format(line, @"\\t").ToString());
            Console.WriteLine( line);
            counter++;

            if (counter == 100)
                break;

        }
        file.Close();
```

And guess what the content of the "line" is still the same ... can anyone help me up with this little problem ?
what else did I try ?
line.Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, ",");
string.empty...
"\n"
Best regards

Comment: If any of the `A,tampqer,n:.jpg` or `A\tampqer\tn:\t\t` are file names, you should know that colon ':' is an illegal character for file name on Windows. Also, while I believe `@"C:\\german-czech.txt"` will work, you might want to use either `@"C:\german-czech.txt"` or `"C:\\german-czech.txt"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need

```
line = line.Replace(line[i], ',');
```

It doesn't change it in place. It returns a *new* string.

You also don't need to transverse the string one by one. `Replace` will replace every occurrence in the string. So instead of your:

```
    //replace /t doesnt work
    for (int i = 0; i < line.Length; i++)
    {
        if (line[i] == '\t')
        {
            line.Replace(line[i], ',');
        }
    }
```

Just have:

```
line = line.Replace("\t", ',');
```

(This is correcting your code. But I think mrzli in his comment got the real error.)

Comment: "The given path's format is not supported." for that statement "File.Move(f.FullName, Path.Combine(f.DirectoryName,line.ToString() + f.Extension));" -but only if i use "line.toString()" with other names it works."line" looks now like "A,ampqer,n:,," ...

Comment: ok, you both were right . I replaced ":" it as well. Thanks a lot :)